# skip handling a row if it's already present in result set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m working with big data and try to optimize my query. Is it possible to skip handling those rows which are already present in the result set?

Look at `AHTUNG` comment in my query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS
SELECT bg2.id, bg1.property4 -- may be select kuf1.id and then pull property4 for each row in result set? id is PK, but property4 isn't indexed
FROM big_table bg2
JOIN correlating_table cor
    ON  bg1.property4 = cor.id2

-- AHTUNG!: Many JOINs,AND & WHERE statements. But I have no need to do that 
-- if bg1.id is already present in result set

JOIN big_table bg2 
    ON bg1.property4 = cor.id1
WHERE bg1.property1 = bg2.property1 -- AND (in JOIN clause) vs WHEN
AND bg2.property2 = bg2.property2
AND bg1.property2 BETWEEN @from AND @to   
AND bg2.another_table_id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT k.id FROM big_table bg
    JOIN entities e ON bg.entity_id = e.id
    WHERE bg.property4 = bg1.property4 AND bg.property1  = bg1.property1
) 
GROUP BY bg2.id, bg1.property4;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception that SQL works by reading your query and doing the processing step-by-step.

In fact, what SQL does is to read the entire query and generate an execution plan for it.  Then, it executes the plan.  That means that all the joins and group bys and other logic in the query is part of the execution plan.  The presence or absence of values in the data do not (in general) affect execution plan.

So, you can't do what you want with a single query.  You could break the logic into two separate queries, one skipping over the values that are present and the other looking for new values.  This could improve performance, particularly if there are few new values and performance is driven by dealing with large amounts of data.  Or, it could make the performance worse, if the check is too expensive.  You would have to try it out to see what happens on your data on your systems.